Is IEnumerator<out T> extending IDisposable just an implementation detail forced by the C# language
The closest thing I came to find as a valid reason for IEnumerator<out T> extending IDisposable is from this answer that echoes work done by Jon Skeet - like this:

The state machine is built so that finally blocks are executed when an
iterator is used properly, however. That's because IEnumerator
implements IDisposable, and the C# foreach loop calls Dispose on
iterators (even the nongeneric IEnumerator ones, if they implement
IDisposable). The IDisposable implementation in the generated iterator
works out which finally blocks are relevant to the current position
(based on the state, as always) and execute the appropriate code.

There is another point that comes often is that it saves the compiler a check when using foreach. Related again is that when using foreach we don't have any other way of disposing the IEnumerator, but C# has to do it for us because the object is not explicitly exposed to us to call Dispose() ourselves.
So, if there was no yield in C# (no iterator state machines) and the way foreach is implemented somehow allowed us to Dispose manually - what other reason would there be to have IEnumerator<out T> explicitly extending IDisposable?

You can call Dispose manually for most disposable things, but they still implement IDisposable. Being able to manually call Dispose isn't a reason to not implement IDisposable, but not being able to manually call Dispose is a reason for IEnumerator to implement IDisposable.

Why? Even before iterator methods, you could need to write an implemenation by hand that would also need proper disposing. For example, if your enumerable collects data from files - the currently open file needs to be closed if enumeration is interrupted.

Isn't "some enumerators hold unmanaged resources" enough of a reason for it to implement IDisposable?

Not entirely sure I understand the question here, it seems to end with "In a hypothetical world, would it need to enforce IDisposable?", and the answer to that would be that in a hypothetical world, anything could exist.

Enumerators aren't created by yield alone. That's  used to create iterator methods. LINQ and other libraries like MoreLINQ, Reactive Extensions, Linq.Async use custom tightly controlled enumerators to implement their functionality, eg batching rows by time. These have to be cleaned up deterministically which mean IDisposable is needed

Sometimes enumerators can hold resources that need to be disposed of. For example, I could create an API that allows you to read a file line by line, and also allows you to read it multiple times.
var lines = new FileLines("foo.csv");
foreach (var line in lines) {
    // ...
}
// some time later...
foreach (var line in lines) {
    // ...
}

It makes a lot of sense here for FileLines.GetEnumerator to return an enumerator that holds a StreamReader and implements IDisposable, and calling Dispose would dispose that StreamReader.
Had IEnumerator<T> not inherited IDisposable, methods that iterate through an IEnumerable<T> would need to be very careful. foreach takes care of disposing the enumerator, but what if that method is not using foreach? An unwieldy try...finally would be needed to handle disposable enumerators:
void SomeGeneralMethodThatWorksOnEnumerables(IEnumerable<string> lines) {
    var enumerator = lines.GetEnumerator();
    try {
        // ... iterate using the enumerator ...
    } finally {
        // the enumerator might need to be disposed!
        var d = enumerator as IDisposable;

        // before C# 6, this would have been "if (d != null) { ... }", even longer!
        d?.Dispose();
    }
}

Since IEnumerator<T> implements IDisposable, this can be simplified with just a using statement (or a using declaration).
using (var enumerator = lines.GetEnumerator()) {
    // iterate...
}

or
using var enumerator = lines.GetEnumerator();
// iterate...



Related again is that when using foreach we don't have any other way of disposing the IEnumerator, but C# has to do it for us because the object is not explicitly exposed to us to call Dispose() ourselves.

Being able to call Dispose() manually isn't a reason for IEnumerator<T> to not inherit IDisposable though. You can manually call Dispose on many things, but they nonetheless implement IDisposable.
The whole point of the IDisposable interface is to provide a unified interface for disposing things that might need to be disposed. Code that works with IEnumerator<T>s is very likely to be responsible for disposing it (after all, that code is likely what created the enumerator in the first place, by calling GetEnumerator). Therefore, IEnumerator<T> inherits IDisposable.
